# Can you mimic having JavaScript disabled?

Tags: javascript

A new requirement just came up at work, where the website I'm working on needs to work even if JavaScript is disabled.

Unfortunitely, my place of work is so locked down that ***disabling JavaScript has been disabled***. In other words, ***I can not disable JavaScript, it is always enabled*** even through developer tools.

As far as I'm aware, IE9 is the only browser requirement. I'm unable to install any software or plugins due to lack of priviledges.

The site was created with ASP.NET WebForms in 2.0 and 3.5. However, I'm not asking how to solve ASP.NET issues related to JavaScript being disabled.

Simply removing all JavaScript will not produce the results I'm looking for.

What I can do is use any JavaScript libraries, though I'm not sure how that's helpful.

Comment: This sounds like a problem of the requirements and policies, not of the technology.  Your employer has issued a requirement which their own policies forbid.  One of those two things needs to change.

Comment: If your work won't trust you to have admin privledges then you need to tell your employer that you are unable to do your job without them.  If they say they won't give them to you, then tell them to find a new employee.

Comment: If it is not an intranet application, you can try http://www.dejavu.org/emulator.htm

Comment: comment out the script tag?

Comment: Actually, I'd say that removing all JavaScript _will_ produce the results you're looking for, in that it will give you exactly the same behavior as having JavaScript disabled.

Comment: @Kolby it is not that simple.

Comment: Is there a specific functionality you have in mind where you don't know how to get it to work without JS?

Comment: @David I couldn't agree more. Before I started working here, I was told not to question things, despite how absurd they might be. I'm just hoping someone might know of a work around.

Comment: But ditto the first two comments; your employer can't very well expect you to test your site as-is in a JavaScript-disabled environment if they don't give you the power to disable JavaScript in your test environment.

Comment: Don't question things? That's not conducive to a productive working environment. Some things *have* to be challenged.

Comment: @user1197834: `"Before I started working here, I was told not to question things"` - I *really* hope you're actively looking for a new job.  If this company's goal is to never let you be more than an order-taker, it's not a good long-term career.

Comment: It's a sign that you're going to be expected to magically do things that may not be possible - and if you're not able to meet impossible expectations, you'll be gone. By the time they realize their mistake, it will be too late.

Comment: BTW, I think this is a fine question and didn't deserve the downvote.

Comment: @David Belive me when I say I've made this known. Thankfully it's only a short term contract.

Comment: Contract? That explains *everything*.

Comment: @Selcuk dejavu.org is blocked.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ removing/commenting out the Javascript does not do what you want?  Is something in your server-side adding JS dynamically to your markup?

Comment: @ScottSauyet ASP.NET adds JS server-side, there is no way to turn that off. Dealing with ASP.NET when JS is disabled is a whole other issue.

Comment: @ScottSauyet You also need to worry about the <noscript> tag, it's only activated/shown when JS is disabled in the browser.

Comment: @user1197834: The second issue (NOSCRIPT) would be easy: just include the content without the <noscript> tag.  But the first issue does make this almost impossible.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I think that will work, thanks for the idea. I guess one of the bigger issues I'm having is that I want to test this as accurately as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome falls back to a non-administrator installation when you don't have admin rights to your box. You'll be able to do whatever you want to it, disabling JavaScript, etc.

Comment: Please read my third paragraph. I'm unable to install software.